# Power Pivot: create (from existing table) unique ID table/formula with multiple columns for many-to-many relationship

Tags: many-to-many, powerquery, powerpivot, distinct-values

I would please like some advice or other suggestions as to what would be the best solution for this problem.

I have 2 different data files that Power Query pulls in and transforms (One stock file, other one Sales). These are both loaded into the Data model and measures added, and then used in various Pivot Table Reports. Both these Data tables have 100 000's of rows and between 30 and 50 columns.

One of the Pivot Table reports I need to combine these to Data files to show stock and Sales. This cannot currently happen because it's a many to many relationship.
I'm adding all the Pivot Table columns (Site, Article, Barcode, StockQty, etc) from the Stock file and just want to add the Sum of Sales Value and Units from the Sales File when the *BranchCode/Site* and *Barcode* matches between Stock and Sales tables. The Unit and PackSize info comes from a dimension table.

**Expected Outcome example**
[image]

**I've tried:**

- Just adding the sum measure from the sales file to my Pivot Table report

`Total Sales:=CALCULATE(SUM(DailySalesRaw[SalesValue]),DailySalesRaw[SalesQuantity]>0)`

But then all the values are the same because of the many to many relationship.

[image]

- Adding a measure to my Stock file (Unit_Packsize table are 'Master tables' with distinct *Barcodes*, but they do not include all the *Barcodes* found on the data files). This seem to correctly add the values, but I want to avoid using this table since it's not always up to date and will exclude items not found (Pack size=N/A), thus not all values will be added.

`Sales Total:=CALCULATE(SUM(DailySalesRaw[SalesValue]),DailyStockData,UnitSize_PackSize)`

[image]

- Tried aggregating the 2 data files in Power Query to create a single table that has 2 columns with unique ID's(*Site* and *Barcode*). I can then create one to many relationships, which should solve the problem. I believe there should be an easier way....

**Question:**

What is the best way to do this:

1. Use Power Query to create a lookup ID table from the Sales data? (This report is run every week, so constantly uses new data files)
2. Is there a formula in Power Pivot Data Model that can sum the total value when the *Site* and *Barcode* match?
3. How to create a lookup ID table that only includes distinct *Site* and *Barcode* from the Sales table in Power Pivot Model? (Without manually creating a table as mentioned above. I've only managed to use distinct with 1 column)

Image of Data Model layout:
[image]

**Relationships**
[image]

Comment: Please add a print screen of the data model

Comment: @RicardoDiaz Data model layout added to the post

Comment: Hi Simone. Looking at the data model and without knowing the details of the relationships between tables, I think you need to implement the star schema to simplify your analysis (google it). Here is a [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/relationships-many-to-many) on how to handle three cases of many to many rels in power pivot/query. Key here is to de-normalize (shape) data through power query and achieve the star schema.

Comment: @RicardoDiaz thank you for the links, I read through them. My Model is basically setup as a star schema (exception of the 1 inactive link). The Sales and the Stock data are both Fact tables, each with a many to one relationship to the other dimension-type tables. I does seem the best would be to just create a single table that has a unique Id (my post question 1 and 3). I guess now I have to figure out how to create an ID table which has BranchCode and Barcode as the columns. Then link the to fact tables with a many to one relationship to it.

Comment: I'm not quite sure you have a Star Schema there, but as I said, It's hard to conclude without all the details and some sample data.

Comment: @RicardoDiaz is there any further information (+ sample data) I can supply that would enable someone to help further?

Comment: Sure, you can upload some sample files to onedrive and share the link here. I'll try to take a look at it

Comment: @RicardoDiaz link with files in: <https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aqas1Hm7qItlgYQQ4S34zpsBtIWONQ?e=g6oEgH> .I've added all the files I've shown in the Data model (removed most, just kept 4 Sites and 4 Articles). You'll probably only need the 2 Fact tables. since I want to create a link between them (using BranchCode and Barcode). The Sales Table is the one I want to sum values for to add to the Stock Table Report. Thanks for having a look!

Comment: Simone please [edit] your question and, based on the sample data provided, add a picture of the expected pivot table result (it can be a manually created excel table, but I need to know exactly what columns and what values should be retrieved)

Comment: @RicardoDiaz I've added a manually created table with expected outcome (used data from example data I posted in there) to the OneDrive folder and a screenshot added to my post, under heading **Expected outcome example**, paragraph above that mentions where columns and details are coming from.

Comment: Simone, what fields match Unit and PackSize table to the other tables?

Comment: That would be the barcode

Comment: Simone, when I join DailyStockData with Unit_PackSize using BarcodeCode and Selling barcode (respectively) there are 6 matching rows and none of them is PK1-12 https://imgur.com/SM0BvVE am I missing something?

Comment: @RicardoDiaz no that is correct, since that barcode is not on the dimension table I supplied. I've updated the expected outcome file in the folder. Sorry about that.

Comment: Thank you Simone. I still can't get the results. maybe there's some cardinality in the relationships between tables that I'm getting wrong.

Comment: @RicardoDiaz thanks for having a look. Is there any more information I can send to help and resolve this?

Comment: Simone, please provide the cardinality of the relationships between the tables

Comment: @RicardoDiaz I added a screenshot of the relationship cardinality to my post as requested. Obviously there is no many-to-many relationship between the 2 fact tables, Sales and Stock, which I'm trying to connect via Barcode and BranchCode.

Comment: Hi Simone, sorry for the delay. Being busy these days. I'll try to take a look at it this weekend

Comment: @RicardoDiaz no problem thank you, I appreciate it. I've been looking at videos and this one might help <https://youtu.be/TXLJTJ8ycuw>, using just a formula. I'm trying different formula versions but no luck yet.